# Mongoose: Trying to use .virtual method to rename

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have to rename the name of the field when using populate.

```
const CategorySchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      unique: true
    },
    featured: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true
    },
    image: String,
    active: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true
    },
    subCategoryIds: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'SubCategory' }]
  },
  {
    timestamps: true
  }
);
export default mongoose.model('Category', CategorySchema);
```

This is my Category Schema.

And here is my SubCategory Schema

```
const SubCategory = new Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      unique: true
    },
    active: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true
    },
    categoryId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category' },
    productIds: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product' }]
  },
  {
    timestamps: true
  }
);
SubCategory.virtual('category', {
  ref: 'Category',
  localField: 'categoryId',
  foreignField: '_id'
});
export default mongoose.model('SubCategory', SubCategory);
```

And here I have a filed `categoryId`, when using populate, I want it to be 'category', So I used `virtual` to create 'category`.
and implemented this

```
const subCategories = await SubCategory.find({}).populate('category');
```

But unfortunately it isn't working, It returns the normal `subCategory` object and there is no category present.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why dont you use `Mongodb` aggregation pipeline, instead of using `mongoose virtuals`, You can use `$lookup` and change `catergoryId` to category while populating.

Try this:

```
const subCategories = await SubCategory.aggregate([{
    $lookup : {
        from : "categories",
        localField : "categoryId",
        foreginField : "_id",
        as : "category"
},{
    $unwind : "$category"
}])
```

`localField` says which field to populate, `from` tells monogdb which collection to populate from, `foreignField` tells mongodb which field to match it for population, and `as` is used for the field in which result will be stored,

`$unwind` is used in the next stage, because `$lookup` returns an array, we need to convert it to category object

Read [Mongodb $lookup documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) for more info.